# Awaited TaskCompletionSource and Channel Reader doesn't resume when SetResult/Write in Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, taskcompletionsource, system.threading.channels

I’m writing a turn-based game, and I have been using async methods to properly control consecutive actions. Whenever the player is prompted to choose objects to interact with, the game manager calls the below asynchronous method for that player (in the script attached to the player object):

```cs
public async Task<List<GameObject>> SubmitObjs(List<GameObject> options, int selN)
{
    List<GameObject> result = new List<GameObject>();
    centralTime.ToggleOutlines(options, 1, true);
    while (result.Count < selN)
    {
        selection = new TaskCompletionSource<GameObject>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        GameObject obj = await selection.Task; //Awaited TCS here...

        if (obj && options.Contains(obj))
            if (result.Contains(obj))
            {
                result.Remove(obj);
                centralTime.ToggleOutlines(new List<GameObject>() { obj }, 1, true);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(obj);
                centralTime.ToggleOutlines(new List<GameObject>() { obj }, 2, true);
            }
    }
    centralTime.OutlineOff();
    return result;
}
```

To allow the player to click on objects that they want to interact with, I have written `Update()` in the same script as below as well:

```cs
private void Update()
{         
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {             
        GameObject DO = DetectValObj();             
        if(DO) selection.TrySetResult(DO); //TCS is Set here...         
    }     
}
```

As you can see, the asynchronous `SubmitObjs()` is supposed to be awaiting the `TrySetResult()` in `Update` so that when the player clicks on the object, it resumes the process to submit the object the player decided.

However, what really happens is that clicking on the objects and running `selection.TrySetResult()` doesn’t resume the processing in `SubmitObjs()`. I tested `DetectValObjs()` and it is transferring `DO` into `TrySetResult()` properly, and what’s more frustrating is that in one in ten tries, `SubmitObjs()` would resume and process with the passed object.

Honestly, I don’t think I understand `TaskCompletionSource` and `SetResult()` properly. I looked up many references and examples, but I can’t figure out why exactly does `TrySetResult()` resumes awaited task only some of the time.

I tried ditching TCS entirely as well, having it replaced with a simple private `GameObject sel`, with `Task.Yield()` if `sel` isn't assigned in `Update()`:

```cs
while (!sel)      
    await Task.Yield();  
obj = sel;
```

This version turned out to be worse, as I found out that `Update()` wasn't getting called at all this time.

What exactly is going on here, and how can I fix this to make them work as intended?

+Edit(2024-01-07): I checked if the `SynchronizationContext` was different in `Update()` and `SubmitObjs()`, and they were both under `UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext`. Making `Update()` asynchronous with `await Task.Yield()` has proven to be ineffective as well.

+Edit(2024-01-09): As per Anton Tykhyy's suggestion, I have tried to replace the use of TaskCompletionSource into System.Threading.Channels. Checking if `SubmitObjs()` and `Update()` were working with the same `Channel<GameObject>` instance has shown that they were in fact different, even though there is but a singular channel reference in the scope of the script. There are no initializations of the Channel other than the declaration in the script (it is declared to be `readonly`).

Comment: How are you calling `SubmitObjs`?

Comment: `SubmitObjs` is called in the Game Manager's script with just an `await` where player choice is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A Partial Answer, but it still answers at least half of it:

I have since broke away from trying to synchronize `Update()` and `SubmitObjs()`. I tried to find a way to get Input for each frame inside `SubmitObjs()` without the need of `Update()`, and I have found a solution of `WaitUntil(() => Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` to detect Mouse click for each frame. Here is the Updated `SubmitObjs()`, using `UniTask` as a replacement:

```cs
public async UniTask<List<GameObject>> SubmitObjs(List<GameObject> options, int selN)
    {
        List<GameObject> result = new List<GameObject>();
        centralTime.ToggleOutlines(options, 1, true);
        while (result.Count < selN)
        {
            await UniTask.WaitUntil(() => Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));
            GameObject obj = DetectValObj();
            if (obj && options.Contains(obj))
                if (result.Contains(obj))
                {
                    result.Remove(obj);
                    centralTime.ToggleOutlines(new List<GameObject>() { obj }, 1, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(obj);
                    centralTime.ToggleOutlines(new List<GameObject>() { obj }, 2, true);
                }
        }
        centralTime.OutlineOff();
        return result;
    }
```

There is still issues with `Physics.Raycast()` not detecting Objects properly, but at least the input is being received each frame properly.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with `TaskCompletionSource` itself but with the shared variable `selection` which you are reading and writing from multiple threads without any synchronization. Nothing guarantees that `Update()` calls `TrySetResult()` on the same `TaskCompletionSource` object that you are assigning in `SubmitObjs()`. Also, multiple updates could happen while `SumbitObjs()` is processing the one it has read, causing updates to be lost. Your idea of how the code ought to work seems to fit the producer/consumer pattern, so the simplest solution for you is to use [`System.Threading.Channels`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) instead of a bare `TaskCompletionSource`.  Channels handle all synchronization details for you and give you an easy to understand abstraction to work with.

```cs
// at top level
private readonly Channel<GameObject> selections = Channel.CreateUnbounded<GameObject>() ;

// Update()
if(DO) selections.Writer.TryWrite(DO);

// SubmitObjs()
while (result.Count < selN)
{
    GameObject obj = await selections.Reader.ReadAsync();
```

Comment: How can you know there are multiple threads? Even if there were, how can you know SubmitObjs may be called a second time before the first time returns?

Comment: If there was only one thread, you wouldn't have these problems. As for Update() being called a second time, one general rule of thinking about multithreaded programs is to consider every interleaving of logical threads of execution consistent with the use you are making of synchronization primitives. Another is to consider that any thread can get paused/stuck any time (except inside a synchronization primitive) for any period. Since you aren't making Update() wait for SubmitObjs(), there is no grounds to assume that the external UI event manager or whatever will call it only once.

Comment: This solution seems to not work, akin to the first version posted above. I checked if the channel was properly writing & reading with `Reader.TryPeek(out obj)` in `Update()`, and it was writing and reading fine. For some reason, `SubmitObjs()` just doesn't resume awaited `Reader.ReadAsync()`, much like how TCS version didn't resume even when after `SetResult`. I still don't understand why would an async method, even if it was awaited from a different GameObject, would desynchronize with the rest of the script.

Comment: To get simple things out of the way, have you checked if both methods work with the same channel/TCS instance when SubmitObjs is stuck? If yes, then look into what task scheduler(s) you are using.

Comment: Comparing `GetHashCode()`s revealed that they were, in fact, different object instances (I was unsure if this was the valid way to do this so I tried many different solutions). I'm unsure how there could be two different channels when I'm working in a singular object with the same reference for the channel. Why would this happen, and how can I rectify this issue?

Comment: Okay, them being different channel instances answers your initial question. (Objects with same `GetHashCode()` values may be different instances - use `Object.ReferenceEquals()` - but never vice-versa.) Why they are different is an entirely separate problem. I can't say why this would happen as your code snippets don't cover how you are creating instances of whatever `Update()` and `SubmitObjs()` are instance methods on.

Comment: `Update()` and `SubmitObjs()` are instance methods on Player Objects, which I have them already existing from the beginning (as in, I don't create them via script after the scene is loaded).