# Singular System.Threading.Channel reference returns multiple instances in different Methods

Tags: unity-game-engine, async-await, system.threading.channels

This question is an extension of: [Awaited TaskCompletionSource and Channel Reader doesn't resume when SetResult/Write in Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769301/awaited-taskcompletionsource-and-channel-reader-doesnt-resume-when-setresult-wr)

In a singular unity script, I have a structure like below (simplified from original for conciseness):

```
private readonly Channel<GameObject> selection = Channel.CreateUnbounded<GameObject>();

public async Task<GameObject> AwaitedFromAnother()
{
    GameObject obj = await selection.Reader.ReadAsync(); //Read From Channel
    return obj;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GameObject DO = DetectValObj(); //Helper Method for Raycast Object Detection...
        if (DO)
        {
            selection.Writer.TryWrite(DO); //Write Into Channel
        }
    }
}
```

`AwaitedFromAnother()`  is awaited from a different object's component, and it's supposed to await the input from `Update()`  below. However, even when I click on a valid object and trigger `selection.Writer.TryWrite(DO)` (I checked by calling `selection.Reader.TryPeek()` right after), `AwaitedFromAnother()` still remains stuck on `await selection.Reader.ReadAsync()` most of the time.

I checked if I was writing to and reading from a valid Channel, and as it turns out that there are multiple instances of `Channel<GameObject>` under the same reference of `selection`. Multiple checks of `GetHashCode()` revealed that they were two different `Channel<GameObject>` in both `AwaitedFromAnother()` and `Update()`.

The Object this script is attached to is in the initial scene to begin with, so there aren't any code instantiating the component instance.

Why would a singular `Channel<GameObject>` reference house two different instances of Channels, and how do I force it to definitely be singular throughout the script?